# Python function import hierarchy

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have the following project:

```
- root
  -addons
    -module1.py (contains the function func1)
  -folder1
    -module2.py (contains func2 which needs to use func1)
main.py (contains call to func2)
```

I am trying to run `main.py`

I do the imports as such :

```py
from addons.module1 import func1
from folder1.module2 import func2
```

But when I call `func2` within main I get a

> name 'func1' is not defined

How to make sure `func2` knows `func1` through the magic of imports ?

I am using python 3.7.

Comment: `func1` needs to be defined in the globals accessible to `func2`, in `module2.py`. Python has *lexical scope*, not dynamic scope. you would import `func1` into `module2.py`

Comment: Did you import `func1` in `module2.py`?

Comment: No I wanted to import `func1` once for all subsequent uses. It's a `numba.jit` function so loading it the first time takes a bit of time but reusing it is extremely fast. If i load it every time I call `func2` it's losing its appeal. Or would `func1` be kept into memory when running `main` even if imported from within `module2` ?

Comment: Yes, imports are cached

Comment: oh ok all good then. Do you want to post an answer or shoudl I just delete the question ?